# MATCH returns #N/A But DO WORK right at evaluation (F9)

Tags: excel-2010

I'm using match to find a row number for index using multiple criteria, and wrote this syntax:

```
=MATCH(1,($AW$2=DATA!$A:$A)*($AW$3=DATA!$B:$B)*($AV6 =DATA!$C:$C),0)
```

But I'm receive #N/A as a result, it's not true, because if I evaluate it manually with F9, it does return the right result
what is wrong?
what should I do?
maybe some program options in EXCEL itself?

Comment: Feedback please. Does my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Response, but it isn't a issue. 
I just forgot to place a formula in the {} 
Or ctrl+shift +enter 
Because it's an array formula. 
Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

> Go to Formulas Menu > Calculation Options > Select `Automatic`.

This shall calculate all formula as soon as you type them.

Comment: Thanks for Response, but it isn't a issue. I just forgot to place a formula in the {} Or ctrl+shift +enter Because it's an array formula. Works like a charm